# Nginx not getting the real visitor IP in server block

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, x-forwarded-for

I am using a loadbalancer in my current setup, requests come from ip `10.71.128.13`.

I am using Nginx as a front to a Gunicorn backend. I want to get the real IP address of the visitor and log it (not the loadbalancer IP).

My nginx.conf:

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

# GET REAL IP
set_real_ip_from   10.71.128.12;
set_real_ip_from   10.71.128.13;
set_real_ip_from   10.71.128.14;
real_ip_header     X-Forwarded-For;
```

My server block 'example.conf'

```
# HTTPS
server {

   etc....

location / {

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_buffering on;
}
}
```

An example log entry:

```
10.71.128.13 - - [10/Jun/2014:13:27:58 +0100] "POST /example/ HTTP/1.1" 200 25 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"
```

Sadly this configuration just returns the loadbalance IP and not the visitor's IP address... Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this an AWS loadbalancer?  If not, what is it?  The web server is quite correctly logging at the moment, so the only ways to fix it are **either** to get a load-balancer that routes rather than proxies the client requests, **or** to get the load-balancer to send the client IP as an additional datum that the server might be told to log - and to do the latter we need to know what kind of LB it is.

Comment: It's an OVH loadbalancer... This configuration works with just a simple HTTP server and I can get the correct IP. But when using upstream (socket to connect to gunicorn) it seems to break...

Answer (score 0):

When you have SSL pass-through loadbalancing the proxy can't add the required headers so you'll never know the originating IP